# Persistent session after signout Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase Authentication for my app.
I can log / register correctly except when another user was log previously.

Exemple :
I am log, and I want to signout. Like this :

```
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  signOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
```

```
IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          signOut();
                          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                              .pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return const OnBoardingPage();
                              },
                            ),
                            (_) => false,
                          );
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.logout))
```

So I came back to my onboarding page but I'm not fully disconnected.

I know it because I can display my email on the onboarding page (where normally no one can be connected)

So, I need to restart the app, and then, I am no longer connected and user mail can't be displayed.
I think it is something about cache but not sure.

I want to know how to fully disconnected my account of my app. and avoid persistent session after logout.

Answer (score 0):

check the user currently signed in or not in splash screen

```
if ( FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
        // signed in
          return HomeScreen();
        } else {
         return LoginScreen();
        }
```

function to sign out

```
 Future<void> signOut(BuildContext context) async {
try {
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (BuildContext context) =>  LoginScreen()));
}catch(e){
   print("signout err:"+e.toString());
  }
}
```

}

Comment: It doesn't resolve the problem that the user session is still persistent

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue for quite some time and have tried various ways of correcting it, including the suggestions here and manually clearing all variables on sign-out.  Hot reload persists the previous data but hot restart solves the issue.  This issue persists in production too and is driving me nuts.

If you're using shared preferences it might be worth you having a look at that is the only advice I can give right now. I am about to take a deep dive into this so will come back if and when I find anything.

Comment: Oh Thanks I am not alone. Thanks for sharing your issue too ! I keep working on it

Comment: I have solved the issue for me.  I was saving the user id globally on successful sign-in.  I was also saving a firebase document reference to the users' database data globally that took in the global user id as a parameter (the latter I set in the Global class itself).  If you're doing the same have a close look at the flow in which this happens.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I do the same. User id is saving globally. I will check this and edit OP if it's working. Thanks for your help !

Comment: No worries.  Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some times.

I had a User(currentUser) who was final in my code and all my queries use this final.

I switch final to dynamic. After that, I set user to null when signOut.
But after that, when user wanted to connect with another account, it take the old user's document.

So when user log with new account (or create a new one), I set currentUser with the new one and also the document reference.

Unfortunately I can't provide some code for contract reason, hope this can help someone.